# VS code default action on auto-fix missing unimplemented abstract methods (typescript)

Tags: typescript, abstract-class, visual-studio-code

when I extends abstract class (Typescript) in VS code and not implement abstract methods in it yet, VS code offer to me automatic fix. When I click on it, it adds unimplemented abstract methods, and inside all of them put this code:

```
throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
```

Is there way to configure this behaviour? Instead of throwing error, I want to print to console (console.error()). And ideally print class name and method name.
Is something like that even possible? If not with that names, so at least to change it to console.error instead throwing error?

The problem is, that when I have lot of abstract method, and all of them are not crucial for program executing, I want to only know, that something is not ready overriden. And manually earse all that error throwing is not really effective solution (probably faster would be copying all abstract methods from abstract class and addinf body to it...)

Any opinion?

Thanks!